# Что означает этот код?

Tags: c++, классы

Что означает этот код?

```
struct A {
    compl A() noexcept = default;
};
```

Comment: Посмотрите что такое `compl`  в вашем проекте. Вероятно, это какой-то define.

Comment: Да это же деструктор! [compl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/compl)

Comment: Почему вопрос закрыли?

Comment: Закрыли, потому что он не обозначает конкретную проблему. Подобные вопросы бесполезны для сообщества.

Comment: @user207200 проблема - непонятный код, который надо объяснить. Множество вопросов подобных тут видел. Собственно, справа можно увидеть это в "Похожие"

Comment: мне кажется, что вопрос закрыли, потому что большинство просто не знает, что такое `compl`. И как это все работает:)